# refresh UItableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The orders are being stored as `Order` objects: `let orders = [Order]()`

The idea is to call my API every second and when a new cell is created, the table should show the new cell.

```
        var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.4, target: self, selector: "GetOrders", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

this code does refresh my function to get data but repeats the cell !!

so in the beginning of `GetOrders` function I erase the array then upload it with new array from API.

```
func GetOrders (){

orders = []
```

but the code crushes when the new order is deleted from database. it shows int he table. When I click on it to returns ' index out of range' because of this function

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    let order =  orders[indexPath.row]
    guard orders.count > indexPath.row else {
        print("Index out of range")
        return
    }

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewControllerIdentifer") as! OrderDetailsController
    viewController.passedValue = order.id
    self.present(viewController, animated: true , completion: nil)



}
```

*UPDATE*

```
func GetOrders (){

    orders = []
    print("hi")

    let urlStr = "api/orders"
    let url = URL(string: urlStr)


    let user = "api"
    let password = "Apipass"



    var headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Authorization": "Basic YXBpdXNlcjpBcGlBdXRoUGFzczIwMTchQCM="
    ]


    Alamofire.request(url!, method: .get ,encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in

        if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value as AnyObject? {
            //Handle the results as JSON
            let data = JSON(value)


            for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in  data[0] {
                //Do something you want



                let logo = subJson["family"]["logo"]

                let logoString = "img/\(logo)"



                if let  date = subJson["family"]["updated_at"].string {
                    print(date)
                    if let cleintName = subJson["client"]["name"].string {



                                                    let info = Order(shopname: shopname, shopaddress: shopaddr, clientName: cleintName, ClientAddress: clientAddres, PerferTime: time, Cost: subtotal , date : time , Logo : logoString ,id : id)



                                                    self.orders.append(info)


                                                }

                                                self.tableview.reloadData()

                                            }

                                        }
```

Comment: i guess your cells are duplicating every seconds..?

Comment: @AnilKumar please look at my updated question

Comment: are you reloading the tableview once you get the data from the api..?

Comment: yes by `self.tableview.reloadData()`

Comment: can you show the api function as well..?

Comment: check my question please @AnilKumar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144193/discussion-between-anil-kumar-and-leo0019).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going on the mainthread?

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```